# Fresh install can't get apache2 webpage to show up

Tags: apache2

I can't get the basic apache web server working .. 
IF I try to connect with a local web browser to localhost I get nothing.. juts an error saying it can't connect.. when I run status it says active (running) see below..

This is a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04.3

I am trying to get Magento 2 running but can't even get the basic webpage to work?

-Ken

```
root@flintmagento:/var/www/html# systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-11-25 15:47:22 EST; 3s ago
  Process: 16017 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17733 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17815 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17819 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 2249)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─17819 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17820 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17821 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17822 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17823 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─17824 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Nov 25 15:47:21 flintmagento systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 25 15:47:22 flintmagento systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'localhost' actually directs to this system?  Is this server on your fresh install or is it on a system separate from your computer you're testing on?

Comment: I am logged on to the OS itself.. yes I am sure local host hits the box.  When I type localhost in the browser it changes to the local IP of the host.